# transmission-daemon.serviceJob for transmission-daemon.service failed

Tags: raspbian, services

I followed an italian guide (http://maxtrixnix.blogspot.it/2013/08/raspberry-pi-come-installare-e.html)  to set Transmission on Raspberry Pi and I get the error:

```
Reloading transmission-daemon configuration (via systemctl): transmission-daemon.serviceJob for transmission-daemon.service failed. See 'systemctl status transmission-daemon.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
 failed!
```

Result of the command

```
systemctl status transmission-daemon.service
```

is

```
● transmission-daemon.service - Transmission BitTorrent Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/transmission-daemon.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2016-07-22 17:11:48 UTC; 4min 43s ago
  Process: 1357 ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2102 ExecStart=/usr/bin/transmission-daemon -f --log-error (code=exited, status=255)
 Main PID: 2102 (code=exited, status=255)
```

Result of command

```
sudo journalctl -xn
```

is

```
-- Logs begin at Fri 2016-07-22 16:22:29 UTC, end at Fri 2016-07-22 17:17:28 UTC. --
Jul 22 17:11:48 MyPi sudo[2089]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jul 22 17:11:50 MyPi sudo[2126]: pi : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/etc/transmission-daemon ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/etc/init.d/transmission-daemon stop
Jul 22 17:11:50 MyPi sudo[2126]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by pi(uid=0)
Jul 22 17:11:50 MyPi systemd[1]: Stopped Transmission BitTorrent Daemon.
-- Subject: Unit transmission-daemon.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit transmission-daemon.service has finished shutting down.
Jul 22 17:11:50 MyPi sudo[2126]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jul 22 17:17:01 MyPi CRON[2170]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jul 22 17:17:01 MyPi CRON[2174]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul 22 17:17:01 MyPi CRON[2170]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jul 22 17:17:28 MyPi sudo[2190]: pi : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/etc/transmission-daemon ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/journalctl -xn
Jul 22 17:17:28 MyPi sudo[2190]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by pi(uid=0)
```

Comment: validate the changes has been done in the transmission-daemon configuration. Ensure there are no typos in the configuration. Check the ownership in the config, are you using a custom user? 
 **before changing anything in /etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json STOP the daemon**

Comment: @JoePlatano  I use the pi user, and I followed every step in the guide